# How do you create husk and stray spawners?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have tried to make them by using this for example:

```
/setblock ~0 ~1 ~0 mob_spawner 0 replace {SpawnData:{id:{ZombieType:6},SpawnCount:1,SpawnRange:4,maxNearbyEntities:6,Delay:20,MinSpawnDelay:60,MaxSpawnDelay:120}
```

But it just makes a pig spawner. I know `ZombieType:6` spawns a husk, but what is wrong with this command? The same goes for strays `SkeletonType:2b` is the tag but the command won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you have set the `id` to `{ZombieType:6}`. A husk's `id` is still just `Zombie`, `ZombieType` is a separate tag that it has.

Try the following instead:

```
/setblock ~ ~1 ~ mob_spawner 0 replace {SpawnData:{id:Zombie,ZombieType:6},SpawnCount:1,SpawnRange:4,maxNearbyEntities:6,Delay:20,MinSpawnDelay:60,MaxSpawnDelay:120}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a much easier way:

```
/give (minecraft username) minecraft:mob_spawner
```

Now get the spawn egg for the mob you want and right click with the egg in your hand on the spawner and it will change to the chosen mob!

Comment: While easier for a basic mob, this is much more limited than directly setting NBT data.